# Why does the console display the incremented number?

Tags: javascript

In this little javascript snippet, I do some basic math.

```
var num = 42;
var sum = function () {
    console.log("here is the number: " + num);
}

num = num + 1;

sum();
```

---

```
var num = 42;
num = num + 1;
var sum = function () {
    console.log("here is the number: " + num);
}

sum();
```

In either case the output I see in the console is 43.

I'd expect that to be 43 *only* in the second block of code since I'm adding +1 to `num` *before* I'm assigning the variable `sum`.

Since I've declared and assigned my variables I'm assuming there's no hoisting here and everything gets executed in the displayed order.

What am I missing?

Comment: You aren't calling `sum()` here. What is generating this output?

Comment: Right. I just slightly edited the code example. Still valid.

Comment: In the first example you are incrementing the variable before you call the function.

Comment: @csmckelvey has it right. Sum is defined first, but not called until after you incremented.

Comment: calling sum();
num = num+1; in that order will give you 42, the answer to the question of life the universe, and everything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your console.log is inside of your sum function.

It only gets executed when you call that function, *not* when that function is defined.

In both cases you are calling the sum function after you increment the number.

To get the output 42 you will need to move the sum function above where you increment the number.

```
var num = 42;
var sum = function () {
    console.log("here is the number: " + num);
}

sum(); // => 42

num = num + 1;

sum(); // => 43
```